# Музыка в Java(mp3)

Tags: java

Каким образом можно реализовать проигрывание музыки в java? Я пробовал нижеприведенный способ(не работает), но там используется фотмат wav.
Как можно загружать музыку в формате .mp3(желательно пример кода)

```
package t4;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.net.URL;

public class Mainn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url = Mainn.class.getResource("l.wav");
        AudioClip clip= Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            clip.loop();
            Thread.sleep(200);
            clip.stop();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("l2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Если Вам дали исчерпывающий ответ, то закройте вопрос, нажав на зеленую галочку рядом с правильным ответом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что-то полезное можете поискать [тут](https://www.google.ru/?client=opera#q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20mp3%20java).

Ну а вообще лучше использовать [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html).

Я подключил библиотеку к **maven** проекту:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>javazoom</groupId>
<artifactId>jlayer</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Добавил данную библиотеку в jar-ник с помощью **maven-assembly-plugin**:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    <descriptors>
        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**assembly.xml**

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-
    plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-
    assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/
    assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>with-dependencies</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>false
        </useTransitiveDependencies>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>org.easytesting:*</exclude>
            <exclude>junit:*</exclude>
            <exclude>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-
            report-plugin</exclude>
            <exclude>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Эта библиотека оказалось очень простой в использовании, нужно было всего лишь создать объект класса **javazoom.jl.player.Player** и далее вызвать у него метод **play()**.

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(soundFile.getPath());
Player player = new Player(stream);
player.play();
```

Comment: всё то отлично работает, но всё же, думаю проще будет скачать эту библиотеку и импортировать в проект так, как сказал dDevil в своём ответе. (см. второй ответ). **Плюс** я Вам всё же поставлю, код ведь работает.

Comment: все прекрасно работает

Comment: @L'Esperanza ну а что мешает просто подключить зависимость в Maven и использовать библиотеку?

Answer (score 6):

Стандартными средствами сделать это не получиться, поэтому подключи к проекту этот [джарник](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources/jlayer1.0.1.zip).

[Как добавить библиотеки JAR в проект? **Eclipse**](http://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-JAR-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Eclipse-(Java))

А далее, чтобы воспроизвести mp3-файл достаточно:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class Mainn {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Sleep Away.mp3");
         Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);

         playMP3.play();

    } catch(Exception e) {/* NOP */}
  }
}
```

Comment: Ссылка не работает

Comment: @L'Esperanza работает, просто там нужно подождать 6 секунд и нажать на skip в правом верхнем углу. Альтернативного источника автор не указал.

Comment: Библиотека не работает.

Comment: @L'Esperanza не знаю, что и как у вас. Но у меня все работает. Правда до прерывания основного потока. Но эта проблема решима

Comment: Одну секунду работает и всё. Как исправить?

Comment: так как исправить то? Я вам **плюс** поставлю если скажите.

Comment: @L'Esperanza сменил библиотеку, т.к та заточена под Swing

Comment: отлично. **Плюс** ваш.